# Можно-ли убрать приложение ,на Qt,в скрытые значки

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt

[image: изобрвжение]

Если это возможно ,то если можете распишите это максимально подробно

Comment: Вы в своем приложении создали иконку трея через QSystemTrayIcon и хотите чтобы она всегда показывалась в "скрытых иконках", которые показываются на панели при клике на стрелку на панели задач?

Comment: Спасибо вам,я не смог найти "QSystemTrayIcon",а теперь всё будет великолепно

Comment: Так, у вас был вопрос о том как создать для своего приложения иконку в трее?

Comment: Вначале да,но я нашёл документацию по QSystemTrayIcon.

Comment: Теперь понятно :) Чтобы вопрос не висел без ответа, добавил пример по вашей проблеме

Answer (score 0):

Добавлю пример создания значка в трее с меню через [QSystemTrayIcon](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsystemtrayicon.html):

```
from PyQt5.Qt import QApplication, QSystemTrayIcon, QStyle, QMenu, QMessageBox, QWidget

app = QApplication([])

mw = QWidget()
mw.show()

# Для примера, иконка трея взята из стилей Qt
icon = app.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_DirOpenIcon)

# Иконка из файла
# icon = QIcon('favicon.ico')

tray = QSystemTrayIcon(icon)

menu = QMenu()
action_settings = menu.addAction("About Qt")
action_settings.triggered.connect(lambda: QMessageBox.aboutQt(None))

action_quit = menu.addAction("Quit")
action_quit.triggered.connect(app.quit)

tray.setContextMenu(menu)
tray.activated.connect(lambda x: menu.exec(tray.geometry().center()))

tray.show()

app.exec()
```